# How to kill zombie process with ppid = 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.6, zombie-process

```
root@9948254b178c:/usr/src/app# ps -ef
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 01:42 ?        00:00:00 node app.js
root          35       1  0 01:43 ?        00:00:02 [javac] <defunct>
root          51       1  0 01:43 ?        00:00:00 [g++] <defunct>
root          66       0  0 01:43 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root          73      66  0 01:43 pts/0    00:00:00 top
root          77      66  0 01:45 pts/0    00:00:00 top
root          79      66  0 01:51 pts/0    00:00:00 top
root          83      66  0 01:54 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

In the table we can see that there are two zombie processes with PID 35 and 51. How could I remove it without stopping the parent (PID=1).

Because the parent is the whole system.

Here is a python script I am running for compiling and running different languages. (C/C++, Python3, Java)

Note: The script for python does not create any zombie process. But the other does. I am running nodejs ecec to run this python script.

```py
import sys
import subprocess
import re

# "python3 run.py "+ json_msg.filename +" "+extensions[json_msg.lang]+" "+json_msg.timeout 
filename = str(sys.argv[1])
extension = str(sys.argv[2])
timeout = str(sys.argv[3])


# for java
def changing_class_name():

    file = open(f"temp/{filename}.java" , 'r')

    newfile = filename
    new_file_content = str()

    for line in file:
        if re.search('^class ',line):
            line = line.strip()
            ls = line.split(" ")

            # print(ls)
            string = ls[1]
            if(string[-1] == '{'):
                new_line = line.replace(string , newfile+'{')
                new_file_content += new_line + "\n"
            
            elif(string[-1]!='{'):

                new_line = line.replace(string , newfile)
                new_file_content += new_line + "\n"
                
        else:
            new_file_content += line 

    
    writing_file = open(f"temp/{filename}.java", "w")
    writing_file.write(new_file_content)
    writing_file.close()



status = True

# we have to get the input file first
try:
    inputfile = subprocess.run(f"cd temp/ && cat input.txt"  ,shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT  , timeout=int("5"))
    
except :
    result = 'Something went wrong while reading input file'
    status = False
    # print('Something went wrong while reading input file')


# for compiling the file
if(status):
    try:
        if(extension == "cpp" or extension == "c"):
            comp = subprocess.run(f"cd temp/ && g++ {filename}.{extension} -o {filename}"  ,shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT  , timeout=int("5"))
            if(comp.stdout.decode()):
                result = comp.stdout.decode()
                status = False

        if(extension == "java"):
            changing_class_name()
            comp = subprocess.run(f"cd temp/ && javac {filename}.java"  ,shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT ,timeout=5 )
    
            if(comp.stdout.decode()):
                result = comp.stdout.decode()
                status = False
        
    except:
        result = 'Something went wrong while compiling the file'
        status = False


# running the file
if(status):
    try:
        if(extension == "py"):
            output = subprocess.run(f"cd temp/ && python3 {filename}.{extension}"  ,shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE ,  input=(inputfile.stdout.decode()).encode() , timeout=int(timeout))
            result = output.stdout.decode()

        elif(extension=="cpp" or extension == "c"):
            output = subprocess.run(f"cd temp/ && ./{filename}"  ,shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE , input=(inputfile.stdout.decode()).encode() , timeout=int(timeout))
            result = output.stdout.decode()

        elif(extension == "java"):
            output = subprocess.run(f"cd temp/ && java {filename}"  ,shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE , input=(inputfile.stdout.decode()).encode() , timeout=int(timeout))
            result = output.stdout.decode()

        # if there is any error we will also add the error
        if(output.stderr.decode() != ""):
            result += output.stderr.decode()
            status = False
        

    except Exception as e:
        result  = "Time limit exceeded"
        status = False
        # print(e)

    

# getting the result and writting it on output.txt
file = open("./temp/output.txt" , "w")
file.write(result)
file.close()


if(status == True):
    print('Successful' ,end="")
else:
    print("Failed",end="")
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why can't you just kill the processes and why do you think you'd need to kill the parent process to kill these zombies? In fact, they are adopted by some init-like process *just because* they are zombies.

Comment: You might take steps to do `comp.stdout.close()` and `output.stdout.close()` after you read the output.  Sometimes that open file handle can cause a pipeline stage to hang.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. When a zombie is adopted by PID 1 it's supposed to reap it automatically. If it's not going away by itself, something is wrong.

Comment: I have limited the pid in the docker-compose file pids_limit: 50. For this reason I need a way to clean up those zombie process.